# 502 error in Nginx AND Apache, node project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-502

I created a very simple, basic Node js project. Using AWS CodePipeline, I've deployed it to Elastic Beanstalk. I'll show the code, this is my app.js:

```
const http = require("http");

const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  res.end("Let's Udaan");
});


server.listen(PORT, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${PORT}/`);
});
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vrikshitcollectionapis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "cmpundhir",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

This is my buildspec.yml if it matters:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
      - npm i
      - npm install nodemon
      
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installed dependencies

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

I've done just about everything. It's a load balanced environment, so I've configured all the security groups and processes/listeners correctly. I've even sshed into my instance and checked if the application is working on port 8081, and it is! I used to have Nginx in my environment before, BUT the error log files were always empty.

I switched to Apache2, and here are the lines that keep repeating in the error_log file:

```
[suexec:notice] [pid 17842:tid 139815705059904] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[ssl:warn] [pid 17842:tid 139815705059904] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 17842:tid 139815705059904] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 17842:tid 139815705059904] AH00489: Apache/2.4.54 () OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 17842:tid 139815705059904] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 17842:tid 139815705059904] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[suexec:notice] [pid 18506:tid 140137494434368] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[ssl:warn] [pid 18506:tid 140137494434368] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 18506:tid 140137494434368] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 18506:tid 140137494434368] AH00489: Apache/2.4.54 () OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 18506:tid 140137494434368] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 18506:tid 140137494434368] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

At this point I'm sure it's an apache/nginx issue. I'm new to all of this, so I am not really sure what to do here. My application is running on its port, all the security groups are configured, everything is working good except for apache/nginx.

Please help me. I've been at it for DAYS.

Here's my httpd.conf

```
"httpd.conf" [noeol] 53L, 1320B
# Managed by Elastic Beanstalk
PidFile /run/httpd.pid

Listen 80
User apache
Group apache
LogLevel warn
TraceEnable off
EnableSendfile on
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# Enable TCP keepalive
Timeout 60
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 60

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

# Since the default "prefork" MPM (Multi-Processing Module) is not fully compatible with HTTP/2
# Need to change Apache’s current MPM to "event" (or "worker").
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so

<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers        10
MinSpareThreads     240
MaxSpareThreads     240
ServerLimit         10
MaxRequestWorkers          250
"httpd.conf" [noeol] 53L, 1320B                                                                       4,9           Top
# Managed by Elastic Beanstalk
PidFile /run/httpd.pid

Listen 80
User apache
Group apache
LogLevel warn
TraceEnable off
EnableSendfile on
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# Enable TCP keepalive
Timeout 60
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 60

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

# Since the default "prefork" MPM (Multi-Processing Module) is not fully compatible with HTTP/2
# Need to change Apache’s current MPM to "event" (or "worker").
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so

<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers        10
MinSpareThreads     240
MaxSpareThreads     240
ServerLimit         10
MaxRequestWorkers          250
MaxConnectionsPerChild 1000000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_http2.c>
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" and "/etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

I expected to run this basic application without any hitches. I configured the port, i added Procfile with the command "web: npm start", everything seems to be configured correctly. I've tried restarting apache, i've even tried to get into their configuration files. I keep getting the 502 gateway error.

Edit: I fixed it. Just changed my code, removed the arrow method, and I also think "setHeader" is depracated, so the server wasn't starting in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying this setting in httpd.conf.
CSS, JS code may not be able to load.

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 1000
KeepAliveTimeout 600
```